# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.UI.ServerPages, Version=10.50.0.0

Tags: 2013, upgrade

We migrated our SharePoint farm from 2010 to 2013

After a month the following error appeared in one of the front end servers:

Event manager error:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.UI.ServerPages,
>   Version=10.50.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=’' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

What does this error mean, and how can we solve this issue?

Comment: did you deploy any custom solution?

Comment: i did not installed any reporting services in new environment, and it no need